# Send value from popup Window(Child) to Parent 

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I want to get a value on popup page,  in one textbox, and send it to the parent window, to another textbox.

How to do that ?

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15217704/passing-a-string-from-javascript-of-popup-window-to-parent-window/15218504#15218504

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but from what I deduce, you want to get the value of a textbox from the parent window in your child window.

You can do something like this -

```
var win = window.open('<Window URL>');
win.contentWindow.SetValueOfTextBox(parentWindowTextBoxValue);
```

Here `win` is the instance of the window you have opened.

You'll have to define `SetValueOfTextBox` function in the new window which you have opened. This function will accept a string and set that value to a textbox on that page. You just have to call that function from the parent window passing the value of the textbox to it.